# How to understand table constraints and assertions for integrity constraints in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

My questions are from reading Database Management Systems, 3rd Edition, by Raghu Ramakrishnan, and Johannes Gehrke. See the relevant quote at the end of this post.

1. Consider the first approach which uses **table constraints**.

   Why "if the  Sailors  table  is  empty,  this  constraint  is 
   defined  (as  per  the  semantics  of  table  constraints)  to 
   always  hold,  even  if we  have  more  than  100  rows  in  Boats"?

   If the Sailors table is empty, then is `SELECT  COUNT  (S.sid)  FROM
   Sailors S` zero?

   Does "Table constraints are required to hold only if the associated
   table is nonempty" contradict "if the Sailors table is empty, this
   constraint is defined (as per the semantics of table constraints) to
   always hold"?
2. Consider the second approach which uses **assertions** instead of table constraints

   How do empty
   tables affect assertions, so that the second approach by assertions
   can solve the problem of the first approach by table constraints?

   The ASSERTION  `smallClub` in the second approach is defined to be
   the same as the last CHECK in the first approach. How can it solve
   the problem in the first approach, when the Sailor table is empty?

Thanks.

> 5.7.3  Assertions:  ICs over Several Tables
>
> Table  constraints  are  associated  with  a  single table,  although 
>   the conditional  expression  in  the  CHECK  clause  can  refer  to 
>   other  tables.  **Table  constraints  are  required  to  hold  only  if 
>   the associated  table  is  nonempty.**  Thus,  when  a  constraint 
>   involves  two  or  more  tables,  the  table  constraint  mechanism 
>   is  sometimes cumbersome and not quite what is desired.  To cover such
>   situations,  SQL supports the creation of assertions, which are
>   constraints not associated  with any one table.
>
> As an example, suppose that we wish to enforce the constraint that the
>   number  of boats  plus  the  number  of sailors  should  be  less 
>   than  100.  (This  condition  rnight  he required,  say,  to qualify 
>   as  a  'small'  sailing club.)  We  could  try the  following  table
>   constraint:
>
> ```
> CREATE  TABLE  Sailors  ( sid  INTEGER, 
>                           sname  CHAR( 10), 
>                           rating  INTEGER, 
>                           age  REAL, 
>                           PRIMARY  KEY  (sicl), 
>                           CHECK  (  rating  >= 1 AND  rating  <= 10) 
>                           CHECK  (  (  SELECT  COUNT  (S.sid)  FROM  Sailors S ) 
>                                     + (  SELECT  COUNT  (B. bid)  FROM  Boats B  ) 
>                                     <  100  ))
> ```
>
> This  solution  suffers  from  two  drawbacks.  It is  associated 
>   with  Sailors,  al- though  it  involves  Boats  in  a  completely 
>   symmetric  way.  More  important, 
>   **if the  Sailors  table  is  empty,  this  constraint  is  defined  (as  per  the  semantics  of  table  constraints)  to  always  hold, 
>   even  if we  have  more  than  100  rows  in  Boats!**  We  could 
>   extend  this  constraint  specification  to  check  that  Sailors  is 
>   nonempty,  but  this  approach  becomes  cumbersome.
>
> The  best 
>   solution  is  to  create an assertion,  as  follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE  ASSERTION  smallClub 
> CHECK  ( (  SELECT  COUNT  (S.sid)  FROM  Sailors S ) 
>          + (  SELECT  COUNT  (B.bid)  FROM  Boats B) 
>          < 100)
> ```

Comment: @melgart Why do you not allow me to self-study a book and ask a question when not understanding it?

Comment: Seems to be saying that the `CHECK` constraints in a table don't come into affect if the associated table is empty (see *"Table constraints are required to hold only if the associated table is nonempty"*). A stand-alone assertion suffers no such limitation

Comment: @matiaselgart: Homework is not off-topic.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' my bad -- looked like a homework problem. been reading too many of those lately and i jumped the gun. sorry Tim.

Comment: @Phil Thanks. (1) The quote "Table constraints are required to hold only if the associated table is nonempty" seems to explain my question.  But does the quote make sense? Does the quote contradict "if the Sailors table is empty, this constraint is defined (as per the semantics of table constraints) to always hold"?  (2)  If considering assertions instead of table constraints, how do empty tables affect assertions, so that the second approach by assertions can solve the problem of the first approach by table constraints?

Comment: @Tim it does seem a little contradictory. Maybe something for the book's editor. Can you file a bug? ;)

Comment: It looks unnatural to impose a constraint on sailors, based on the count of boats. Shouldn't the constraint on boats be limited to the boats that the sailor actually used/sailed? (Yes: I know the sailor&boat example)

Comment: I read this and think: this has no practical relevance to databases in any way. I wouldn't get hung up on it. If you create a table constraint you won't get an error if the table has no records.